# Remove component tag in StencilJS

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, stencil-component

I'm trying to remove the called component tag from HTML to prevent some broken CSS from external libraries and just show the inner content.

**something.component.html**

```
<div>
    Hello World
</div>
```

**another.component.html**

```
<div>
   <app-something [config]="somethingConfig"></app-something>
</div>
```

**Then outputs:**

```
 <div>
    <app-something>
      <div>
          Hello World
      </div>
    </app-something>
</div>
```

**And I want:**

```
<div>
  <div>
     Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible due to the nature of web components which Stencil outputs.

What you could do instead: use the CSS rule `display: contents` on your component which prevents it from generating a box in the layout (see https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents, still somewhat experimental).

---

There are also functional components in Stencil (https://stenciljs.com/docs/functional-components) which don't generate a parent element, but those are only available within JSX, so you'll always need at least one parent Stencil component (so that you can render some JSX).

Comment: Thanks but I have a rule like this in third parties library .ui.labeled.button>.button and component tag prevents it from working

Answer (score 0):

A ugly one but it works:

```
// removing the parent wrapper element
removeParentWrapper() {
  // Find an element with the tag name
  const wrapperNode = document.querySelector('app-something');
  if (wrapperNode) {
    // Create a temporary fragment to hold the child nodes of the found element
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // Move each child node from the found element to the fragment
    while (wrapperNode.firstChild) {
      fragment.appendChild(wrapperNode.firstChild);
    }
    // Replace the found element with its child nodes
    wrapperNode.replaceWith(fragment);
  }
}

componentDidLoad() {
  this.removeParentWrapper();
}
```

As said, this works but some reactive functionality will get effected, also - if this component is listening (@Listen) to any emits, then this doesn't work, it's good to use this only with static component.